# Rename file.php to a custom word

Tags: php, html

I want my php file not to be visible in the html document and to put another word instead

[56/5000
I want to write another name instead of writing the name of my php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tvIS.png)

Comment: You can use [url re-writting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) to display some thing different in `html`.

Comment: you can create a [rewrite rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use URL re-writing.

On Apache [Digital Ocean Article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ about.html [NC]
```

will route:

- `http://your_server_ip/about`, because of the rule definition.
- `http://your_server_ip/About`, because the rule is case insensitive.
- `http://your_server_ip/about.html`, because original proper filename will always work.

But I **strongly suggest** *that you stay away from it* as much as is possible. Instead, **start using a framework** like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/) etc. Then you can name your Controller/action anything and would not have to write complex URL re-write rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A href can’t be hidden from a link. But the files can be rewritten and the request URL can be changed to look like this − login.php/5001

Other than this, a post request can be used in the below way −

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="userinfo" value="5001">
    <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

This will expose a single button in the browser.